# Terraform not accepting allow_major_version_upgrade

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform

I have the following rds definition:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "my-rds" {
  allocated_storage    = 20
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.5.57"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  identifier           = "my-db"
  name                 = "somename"
  username             = "${var.RDS_USERNAME}"   # username
  password             = "${var.RDS_PASSWORD}" # password
  db_subnet_group_name = "${aws_db_subnet_group.some-subnet-group.name}"
  parameter_group_name = "${aws_db_parameter_group.some-rds-parameter-group.name}"
  multi_az             = "false"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.some-sg.id}"]
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  backup_retention_period = 30    # how long we re going to keep your backups
  availability_zone = "${aws_subnet.some-private-1.availability_zone}"
  tags {
      Name = "some-tag-name"
  }

}
```

So I am just adding:

allow_major_version_upgrade = true

... and getting

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_db_instance.my-rds: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_db_instance.my-rds: Error modifying DB Instance my-db: InvalidParameterCombination: No modifications were requested
    status code: 400, request id: 2aed626f-6063-4b69-ac37-654bd783fd37
```

?

Answer (score 3):

This may be related to [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2595) github issue or [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10487) one or other similar issues. Seems there is an issue with pending modifications versus applying them immediately. For example if I set up a DB like in your question and attempt to set `allow_major_version_upgrade = true` it fails the first run with the same error but the change happens and running apply again has no pending changes. However, if I also set `apply_immediately = true` it works on the first run without an error.

In addition when attempting to reproduce this I noticed that invalid parameters also produce this error, such as trying to specify an engine version that doesn't exist when changing the `engine_version`.

Answer (score 0):

For a new major release version upgrade you need to use a new parameters group and option group
resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "this"
resource "aws_db_option_group" "this"